# Add hash links to custon js accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, hyperlink, accordion

Ok, I have made a simple accordion in jQuery. It looks like this:
[example](https://jsfiddle.net/bhzoyeku/)

It is super lightweight and working well but I want to add a #hash "reading" ability to it. So if I use a url mydomain.net/faq#acc2 it will open second bar and scroll to it. Can you help me please :)

```
<div id="faq">
  <h4 id="acc1">Question1</h4>
  <div>
    <p>text text text text</p>
  </div>
  <h4 id="acc2">Question2</h4>
  <div>
    <p>text text text text</p>
  </div>
  <h4 id="acc3">Question3</h4>
  <div>
    <p>text text text text</p>
  </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function($) {
    var allPanels = $('#faq > div').hide();

    $('#faq > h4').click(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        $target =  $this.next();
        if(!$target.hasClass('active')){
            allPanels.removeClass('active').slideUp(200);
            $target.addClass('active').slideDown(200);
        } else {
            $target.removeClass('active').slideUp(200);
        }

        return false;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the URL content by using

```
window.location.href
```

and set that to a variable. Then create an "if" statement to query the results against your arguments (the url condition you want given each case).